# Setting up VPN raspberry pi 3

Tags: vpn

I was trying to use raspberry pi 3 for vpn server following this tutorial.  I have VPN client set up on my MacBook and phone, but it says the server is down when I try to open up piVPN page or even SSH or use VNCviewer.

https://www.comparitech.com/blog/vpn-privacy/raspberry-pi-vpn/

Comment: "the server is down" can you be more specific - which server? what **exactly** are you doing, did you complete the tutorial?

Comment: Please edit your question and add the output from following commands when the vpn tunnel is established: `ip addr show` and `ip route show`.

Comment: I started over again on it.  I just completed the "single hop" connection, and that one worked.  I guess something was wrong trying to set up the double hop part- my pi ended up having 2 ip addresses.

Comment: Please make an answer to finish your question and no other try to help you for nothing ;-)

Answer (score 2):

To finish this question with an answer: the OP solved it according to his comment

> I started over again on it. I just completed the "single hop" connection, and that one worked. I guess something was wrong trying to set up the double hop part- my pi ended up having 2 ip addresses.